# PHP How To Calculate Yearly Increase by Given Start and End Year

Tags: php

By given 2 range of year, current population and target population, how to get total population every year by using PHP?

Example:

Year        |        Population

2014        |        100000

2018        |        132000

On paper calculation like this:

132000 / 100000 = 1.0718

so we will get result every year (On paper):

2014 = 100000

2015 = 107187 (100000 * 1.0718)

2016 = 114890 (107187 * 1.0718)

2017 = 123147 (114890 * 1.0718)

2018 = 132000

How to hold previous year variable to get result as above?

This is my PHP code:

```
for($i > $start; $i < $end; $i++) {
    $this->ProjectPopulation->create(); 
    $increase = array(
        'project_id' => $project_id,
        'year' => $i,
        'percent_increase' => $this->percentage_increase($current_population, $target_population, $year),
        'population' => ??? // Problem here
     );
     $this->ProjectPopulation->save($increase); 
 }
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to display the year by year population with php then? And only once? or whenever you want? Where do you get those values from? Your DB or from php? Be more specific.

Comment: @Nighhunter22 I have problem to hold previous year variable. To multiply with 1.0718. Thanks

Comment: You can hold your previous variables with some temporal variables or just using an `array`. Also, i meant about your mysql tag, why is there? If you are asking for something enterely done by php right? Or do you need something like getting values from your database? That's what i need to know

Answer (score 1):

There are two resources I'd recommend you taking a look at:

http://php.net/manual/en/ref.math.php

and

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_math.asp

You can solve this by doing the calculation each time, but it would be faster to use a loop in order to iterate through them all.

So something like this:

```
$population = 100000;
$year = 2014;

//I'd print the first one out prior to the loop, or you could put an if($year == 2014) in the loop, your choice really. 

for(i= 0; i < 4; i++)
{
   //do calculation in here.
   echo "The current years is" . $year;  
   $yearsCalculation = $population * 1.0718;  

   //then save that value for the next time around the loop. 
   $population = $yearsCalculation ; 
   echo $yearsCalculation ;      

   //increase years each time round loop
   $year++;
}
```

If you then want to store it in a MySQL database you might want to have a look at this tutorial:

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp

Hope that helped!

Comment: Your answer is very low quality, you are giving some vague advices, and also why would he want to put only 2 years instead of having variables that get the years he wants?

Answer (score 0):

Solve

```
private function power($current_population, $target_population, $year) {
    $devide = $target_population / $current_population; 
    $pwrdevider = 1 / $year;
    $power = pow($devide, $pwrdevider); 
    return $power;
}

private function percentage_increase($current_population, $target_population, $year) {
    $devide = $target_population / $current_population; 
    $power = pow($devide, 1 / $year);
    $increase = ($power - 1) * 100;
    return $increase;
}

    $start = 2014;
    $end = 2018;
    $diff = $end - $start; 
    for($i = 1, $data = 100000; $i <= $diff; $i++) {  
        $data *= $this->power(100000, 132000, $diff);

        $increase = array(
            'project_id' => 1,
            'year' => $start += 1,
            'percent_increase' => $this->percentage_increase(100000, 132000, $diff),
            'population' => $data 
        );
        print_r($increase); 
    }
```

This is my result

```
Array
(
   [project_id] => 1
   [year] => 2015
   [percent_increase] => 7.1873373728262
   [population] => 107187.33737283
)
Array
(
   [project_id] => 1
   [year] => 2016
   [percent_increase] => 7.1873373728262
   [population] => 114891.25293076
)
Array
(
   [project_id] => 1
   [year] => 2017
   [percent_increase] => 7.1873373728262
   [population] => 123148.87489076
)
Array
(
   [project_id] => 1
   [year] => 2018
   [percent_increase] => 7.1873373728262
   [population] => 132000
)
```

Thanks all